# SQL Server : filtering records that have matching address for an owner, but more than one address number

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, match, filtering

In the data below, looking at the first two records, the first one seems to be an address match, but I need to ignore it because that owner has more than one address number. The third record is the type of match I need because the address matches, and the owner only has one address.

```
OwnerID     Addr_Nbr    Address_A           Address_B
------------------------------------------------------------
3336223     2204138     11 Westbrook CIR    11 WESTBROOK CIR
3336223     2431628     9 Westbrook CIR     11 WESTBROOK CIR
3337465     2328720     4214 School RD      4214 SCHOOL RD
```

How can I select only the records where the address matches, and there is only one address number for the owner? I hope this makes sense.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
select ownerid, max(addr_nbr) as addr_nbr, max(address_a) as address_a
from t
group by ownerid
having count(*) = 1 and
       sum(case when address_a = address_b then 1 else 0 end) = 1;
```

The `having` clause is critical.  It specifies that there is one address and that the "a" and "b" addresses are the same.  I see no reason to include `address_b` in the `select`, since it is the same as `address_a`.

Comment: Why are you doing this in the having clause and not in the where clause? EDIT: Nevermind, misread original question.

Answer (score 1):

Then I guess that the MINimum Address_A would be the same as the MAXimum Address_B

```
select OwnerID, max(Addr_Nbr) as Addr_Nbr, min(Address_A) as Address_A, max(Address_B) as Address_B
from YourTable t
group by OwnerID
having min(Address_A) = max(Address_B)
```